# Do I ever have to git pull more than once?

Tags: git, push, pull

I'm working on a team, and I git pulled a while back from some branch, made a number of changes, pushed my changes to that branch, and now I'm looking to make more changes to that same branch.

Do I have to pull again from that same branch, or are the files I have good to make edits to then push at a later date?

Would I only have to pull again if I know that someone else made a change to that branch since my initial pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not talk to the network unless you explicitly tell it to with a command like `push`, `fetch` or `pull` (which is just `fetch` + `merge`). So yes, you need to `pull` or `fetch` periodically to see changes in the remote repository.

Because you were able to push, we know there were no more changes done to `feature` on `origin`. `git push` will not merge for you, when you push you must be up to date.

> Do I have to pull again from that same branch, or are the files I have good to make edits to then push at a later date?

What makes Git "distributed" is you can continue to make changes locally and later reconcile them with any changes upstream. If you make changes locally, and others make changes remotely, when you `git pull` those changes will be merged together. `git pull` is a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`.

Here's an example where some edits have been done to the branch remotely (commits F and G) and also locally (commits 1 and 2).

```
origin

A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E - F - G [feature]

local

          [origin/master]
A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E [origin/feature]
           \
            1 - 2 [feature]
```

If you try to push this, Git will not allow it. Your branch has "diverged". `git push` will not merge for you. You need to `git pull` to get up to date.

If you `git pull` while `feature` is checked out Git will `git fetch` the latest version and then `git merge origin/feature`.

```
# Illustrating `git pull` as two steps

$ git fetch origin

          [origin/master]
A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E - F - G [origin/feature]
           \
            1 - 2 [feature]

$ git merge origin/feature

          [origin/master]
A - B - C [master]
     \
      D - E - F - G [origin/feature]
           \       \
            1 - 2 - M [feature]
```

Now you're up to date and safe to push.

If you want to check for changes, but not merge them, it's safe to periodically `git fetch`.

Answer (score 3):

If there are other people working on the same branch on a different files, then you will have to git pull before doing git push. 
Otherwise there is no need to git pull again if there is no change on the branch you are working on

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` fetches changes from a remote and integrates them into your branch.  If the remote doesn't have any changes that would be 'new" to your branch, you don't need to use `pull`.

Generally, gits design allows that any number of developers may be collaborating on the same branch(es), even with relatively loose communication among them.  So it may be that it would be useful to you to pull periodically if you have other devs active on your branch, so that your changes don't diverge too much from theirs without periodic merge resolution.

But the only time you *have* to `pull` is when (a) your branch and the remote branch have in fact diverged (i.e. each has changes the other doesn't yet have), and (b) you want to push your changes.  If you try to push without pulling in this situation, git will warn you and refuse the push[1].

So some people make a habit to pull before pushing, and others just push and let git tell them if they have to pull first. And if pushes are frequent and/or you tend to work on isolated branches, then maybe that's all you need from pull; or, again, maybe you work in a way that more frequent pulling will ease the work of merging.  That's just something you and your team have to work out for your project.

---

[1] When git gives this warning that you need to pull, there is a way you might be able to avoid pulling, but it's almost always going to get the wrong result.  It's called force-pushing, and it's only useful when you know you want to lose any conflicting changes.  I mention it only for completeness as it would not apply to the situation you describe.